# Accessing button from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to access a button created inside a ConstraintLayout of a fragment and it ends up returning null. It is actually able to find the ConstraintLayout and the card view inside of it, but not the button or the text view of the card.

Attaching the fragment file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.QuestionFragment"
    android:id="@+id/contraint_layout">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:text="@string/questions_intro"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/add_question_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/add_question"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_view"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.037"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The code that I have written to access it

```java
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_questions, container, false);
        Button addQuestionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.add_question_button);
        addQuestionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Removed layout margins for brevity.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you absolutely, **100%** sure that `fragment_questions.xml` is the xml that you've posted? I don't see any reason why `findViewById()` wouldn't work, unless you're accidentally getting layout files mixed up.

Comment: I closed Android Studio. Stopped the quemu process. Rebuit project. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your Java code Change Button to MaterialButton

```
MaterialButton addQuestionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.add_question_button);
```

Comment: Find view by ID returns null. What you pointed is a problem. But findViewById returns null for that id.

Comment: One More thing in Xml file add height width in MaterialButton Tag.

Comment: Removed layouts for brevity.